# How do I convert Latitude and Longitude coordinates to GPS (NS/EW) coordinates in R

Tags: r, gps, latitude-longitude

Apologies if I'm not using the correct terminology. But I am looking for a way to convert geocoded Latitude and Longitude to a Degree format which shows GPS (NS/EW) coordinates in R.

### Some Examples

#### 1. Toronto, ON, Canada

##### Geocoded Longitude and Latitude (From latlong.net)

```
lat          lon
43.651070    -79.347015
```

##### GPS Coordinates (From Google)

```
43.6532° N, 79.3832° W
```

#### 2. Melbourne Australia

##### Geocoded Longitude and Latitude (From latlong.net)

```
lat          lon
-37.840935   144.946457
```

##### GPS Coordinates (From Google)

```
37.8136° S, 144.9631° E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sample_data = data.frame(
  lat = c(43.651070, -37.840935),
  lon = c(-79.347015, 144.946457)
)

with(sample_data, paste0(
  abs(lat), "° ", ifelse(lat > 0, "N", "S"), ", ",
  abs(lon), "° ", ifelse(lon > 0, "E", "W")
))
# [1] "43.65107° N, 79.347015° W"   "37.840935° S, 144.946457° E"
```